# Is this parametric equation for a smooth floor function solvable for t?

Tags: systems-of-equations, approximation, parametric, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm working on coming up with a smooth approximation of the floor function that doesn't use a Fourier series or a step function. Having exhausted more direct methods, I'm looking to see if parametrizing the equation might help so came up with the following parametric equations for Floor(x):

$$
x(t)=\frac{1}{2}\times\left(t+\frac{i}{\pi}\times\ln\left(\sqrt{2a-\cos(2 \pi t)+1}+i\sqrt{2}\cos(\pi t)\right)\right)
$$
$$
y(t)=\frac{1}{2}\times\left(t-\frac{i}{\pi}\times\ln\left(\sqrt{2a-\cos(2 \pi t)+1}+i\sqrt{2}\cos(\pi t)\right)\right)
$$

These equations should converge to Floor($x$) as $a$ goes to zero. I'm trying to solve $x(t)$ for $t$ so that I can plug it into $y(t)$ for a given $x$. Any ideas if this is solvable?

If it helps, the expression employing the natural log, $\ln\left(\sqrt{2a-\cos(2 \pi t)+1}+i\sqrt{2}\cos(\pi t)\right)$, is derived from the smooth approximation of the triangle wave function.

Thanks!

Comment: What does a represent on this situation? Also, why is i in the paratremazation for a normally real valued function?

Comment: Hi, a is the degree of approximation, and these should equal Floor(x) as a goes to zero. I've updated the OP to reflect this, thanks.

Comment: And I couldn't tell you why i is there, it just popped up when I solved for an integral.

Comment: I don't see any problems with be a being 0 in the above equations, why not just remove the 2a.

Comment: Well it would no longer be a smooth function in that case which is why I've kept it there.